# How can I have an alert sent if the array changes?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

If `NewMessage` changes, I want an alert.  I have tried `live` and `change on` and `bind change`, but nothing works.

Relevant PHP:

```
$message=6;
    $myReturnData["Message"] = $message; 

  //JSON-encode and return
  print json_encode($myReturnData);
```

Relevant jQuery:

```
setInterval(function(){
     $.getJSON("foo.php", function(data){
         var NewMessage=(data.Message); 
         if(NewMessage>0){
             document.title= NewMessage + ' pm';}
             $(NewMessage).live("change", function() {
                alert(NewMessage);
                });
      });
   }, 3000);
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what you are asking.  The question you have written is incomprehensible.

Comment: I want if NewMessage change alert

Comment: I have attempted to interpret your question **"I want if NewMessage change get alert I don't know how can i do i try live change on change bind change but i can't Thanks "** based on your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'change' is not doing what you think it should be. You should store the original message in a variable, then compare it to the new message you're getting. Like this:

```
var currentMessage = '';
setInterval(function(){
     $.getJSON("foo.php", function(data){
         var NewMessage=(data.Message); 
         if(NewMessage>0){
             document.title= NewMessage + ' pm';
             if (currentMessage !== NewMessage) {
                 alert(NewMessage);
                 currentMessage = NewMessage;
             }
         }
    });
}, 3000);
```

Comment: I'd swap the innermost two lines; assignment, then alert.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want function X to run when a variable controlled by the server changes. To that means you are using a polling mechanism.

So if you want your code to know when it receives a different message, you must store the previous message somewhere outside the scope of your callback function.

Most easy way:

```
var lastMessage = 'the server will never ever forever ever return this message';

setInterval(function(){
    $.getJSON("foo.php", function(data){
        // .. arbitrary code
        if (lastMessage != data.Message)
        {
             alert('it changed');
             lastMessage = data.Message;
        }
        // .. more arbitrary code
    });
}, 3000);
```

i don't think the following code makes any sense or would even remotely work, because the *NewMessage* is not a DOM element, is it?

```
$(NewMessage).live("change", function() {
            alert(NewMessage);
            });
```